Is there a workaround to get or receive replied messages
I'm building a WhatsApp chatbot using:
@green-api/whatsapp-api-client sdk for nodejs/JavaScript. After running the bot ,I noticed it receives messages quite alright but doesn't receive the replied messages on a group chat or normal chat.
 module.exports = Handler = (restAPI) => {
const startReceivingNotifications = async () => {
    console.log("Waiting incoming notifications...");
    await restAPI.webhookService.startReceivingNotifications();

    restAPI.webhookService.onReceivingMessageText((body) => {
        console.log(body);



        // Stop receiving notifications after 20 seconds
        restAPI.webhookService.stopReceivingNotifications();
    });

    restAPI.webhookService.onReceivingDeviceStatus((body) => {
        console.log(body);
    });

    restAPI.webhookService.onReceivingAccountStatus((body) => {
        console.log(body);
    });
};

// Start receiving notifications
startReceivingNotifications();

// Restart receiving notifications every 60 seconds
setInterval(startReceivingNotifications, 60000);

return null; };

